# python string must contain 1 digit and 1 letter

Tags: python, string, alpha, digit

I made a funtion that requires input of 2 values in a string. I'm trying to make it so that the input must consist of a combination of 1 digit and 1 letter. Example: 3f 5h
I have the following code but i can't seem to get the condition of digit and alpha to work. Is it because .isdigit and .isalpha are about all characters?

```
def chess(value1, value2):

    if len(value1) == 2 and len(value2) == 2:
        for char in value1, value2:
            if char.isalpha() and char.isdigit():
                print("Input is right format.")
            else:
                print("Input is NOT right format.")
    else:
        print("Input is NOT right format.")

value1, value2 = input('values: ') .split()

chess(value1, value2)
```

Using only

```
if char.isalpha():
```

or

```
if char.isdigit():
```

seems to work. But together they don't.

Comment: Did you look into the documentation for `isdigit` and `isalpha`? Are there any unclear terms or concepts in there I can assist with?

Comment: input always of length 2?

Comment: You probably can use regular expressions for this. For now, you can do `value1[0].isalpha() and value1[1].isdigit()`, and so on.

Comment: sounds like a good place to use a "regular expression" (i.e. regex)

Comment: That worked thanks! I totally forgot about specifying string paramaters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have no clue about regex with my answer but you could do something like this and write a function to check if each space is valid.

```
def validSpaceFormat(space):
    if len(space) == 2:
        if space[0].isalpha() and space[1].isdigit():
            return True
    return False 

def chess(value1, value2):
    if validSpaceFormat(value1) and validSpaceFormat(value2):
       print("Input correct.")
    else:
        print("Input wrong.")

value1, value2 = input('values: ').split()
chess(value1, value2)
```

This is assuming that people will always input moves as "X1 Y2"

`isalpha()` and `isdigit()` only work on characters so you need to index each character in the string to check what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to check if `input` is of length 2.

```
if len(a) == 2:
    if (a[0].isdigit() and a[1].isalpha()) or ((a[1].isdigit() and a[0].isalpha())):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity how does this check for length 2 instead of just checking the first two character of the string...

Comment: @MooingRawr in question `if len(value1) == 2 and len(value2) == 2:` mentioned.

Comment: I'm referring to your comment `Simple way to check if input is of length 2.` which is implying what your code is doing, which is not.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from BrightOne worked like a charm:

You probably can use regular expressions for this. For now, you can do value1[0].isalpha() and value1[1].isdigit(), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def chess(value1, value2):
    regex = "^\d[a-h]$"
    return all([re.match(regex, s) for s in (value1, value2)])
```

`\d[a-h]` will only match one digit followed by one character in "abcfefgh". the `^` and `$` ensure that it only matches strings of length 2. re.match(regex, s) returns None if the string s does not match the regex

Comment: `\d[a-h]` will only match one digit followed by one character in "abcfefgh". the `^` and `$` ensure that it only matches strings of length 2.  re.match(regex, s) returns None if the string s does not match the regex.